# iOS location events not firing in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation

I'm trying to get location events to fire in an iOS app I'm working on, but for some reason the events aren't firing when I change the debug location.

I'm also pretty confused by the XCode/iOS simulator location debug options. There appears to be two different location debug menus. One in XCode and one in the iOS simulator. I've tried changing both, but neither is causing location change events to be fired.

Here is my app code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?
  var isLocationLaunch: Bool = false;
  var locationManager: CLLocationManager!;


  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.isLocationLaunch = (launchOptions?[.location] as! Bool?) ?? false;
    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager();
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.enableLocationServices();
    return true
  }

  func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
  }

  func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
  }

  func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
  }

  func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
  }

  func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
  }

  func enableLocationServices() {
    locationManager.delegate = self

    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
      case .notDetermined:
        // Request when-in-use authorization initially
        NSLog("Requesting location authorization");
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        break

      case .restricted, .denied:
        NSLog("Location authorization restricted or denied")
        // Disable location features
        break

      case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        NSLog("Location authorization allowed when in use")
        // Enable basic location features
        break

      case .authorizedAlways:
        NSLog("Location authorization allowed always")
        // Enable any of your app's location features
        break
    }
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
           didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    NSLog("didUpdateLocations %@", locations);
  }


}
```

And my `info.plist` (with every location permission description I could find):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>GoNote requires location services at all times.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>GoNote required location services at all times.</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>GoNote uses location services to find nearby notes.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>GoNote required location services when in use.</string>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And my background modes capabilities:

[image: XCode background modes capabilities]

The location manager appears to be getting permissions successfully (`"Location authorization allowed when in use"` gets logged).

Also here are the confusing location debug menus:

[image: iOS simulator location debug menu]

[image: XCode location debug menu]

Comment: Did you called **locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()**

Comment: @Sh_Khan Nope. That's probably the problem.

Comment: Ok , try it and confirm

Comment: That was definitely the problem. Go ahead and post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accoding to [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization) this method

```
func requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

> this method runs asynchronously and prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location services. The user prompt contains the text from the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in your app’s Info.plist file, and the presence of that key is required when calling this method. After the status is determined, the location manager delivers the results to the delegate’s locationManager(*:didChangeAuthorization:) method. If the current authorization status is anything other than CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined, this method does nothing and does not call the locationManager(*:didChangeAuthorization:) method

//

While [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423750-startupdatinglocation)

```
func startUpdatingLocation()
```

> Calling this method causes the location manager to obtain an initial location fix (which may take several seconds) and notify your delegate by calling its locationManager(_:didUpdateLocations:) method. After that, the receiver generates update events primarily when the value in the distanceFilter property is exceeded. Updates may be delivered in other situations though. For example, the receiver may send another notification if the hardware gathers a more accurate location reading

Comment: Thank you. Apparently I need to spend a little more time reading the docs before asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you solved the problem. Anyway the debugger location simulator have a lot of bugs.
I struggled for weeks because it worked well then after updating Xcode it stopped work correctly. Sometimes work, sometimes don't. And I am not changing anything regarding location and geofencing.
Obviously I've tried the app on a device and it work always

Comment: Yeah it's solved for now. I've had a similar experience with both Android and iOS location APIs. Some things seem to work for a while and then suddenly stop working without any clear cause. It doesn't help that the app I'm building needs location events when it's in the background or terminated (which is a huge pain to test).

Comment: Same for me, I need to change the location while in background. Well at least you can have a good excuse to take a walk